# Curious about Output of printf

Tags: php, string, printf

Hello today I was reading about `printf` in `PHP`. `printf` outpust a formatted string. I have a string. I was about to format the floating point string like

```
 $str = printf('%.1f',5.3);
```

I know about format `%.1f` means. Here 1 is number of decimal places. If I `echo $str` like

```
echo $str;
```

It outputs

```
5.33
```

I can understand the output because `5.3` is the string and 3 is the lenght of outputed string which is the return value of `printf`.

But see my following code

```
$str = printf('%.1f', '5.34');
echo 'ABC';
echo $str;
```

It outputs

```
5.3ABC3
```

I wonder how it is happening? If we go simple PHP interpolation it should output `ABC` first then it should output `5.33` because we are formatting only `5.33` not `ABC`.

Can any one guide me what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**printf** is like a **echo** command.It display output by itself and it returns length of string which it is displayed.

if you want to get the output into a variable then you need to add

```
$str=sprintf('%.1f',5.3);
echo 'ABC';
echo $str; 
// now the output will be "ABC5.3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
Place echo "<br>" after every line.You will understand how it is happening.

$str = printf('%.1f', '5.34');    output is 5.3
echo "<br>";
echo 'ABC';    output is ABC
echo "<br>";
echo $str;    output is 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf` would Output a formatted string and returns the length of the outputted string not the formatted string. You should be using `sprintf` instead

```
$str = sprintf('%.1f',5.3);
```

The reason for `5.3ABC3`

```
 5.3  ----------------  printf('%.1f', '5.34'); and $str  becomes 3 
 ABC  ----------------  echo 'ABC';
 3    ----------------  length of 5.3 which is $str
```

Comment: I am asking the reason of above output dear?

Comment: `3` is the length of that was returned from `printf`

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = printf('%.1f', '5.34'); // outputs '5.3' and sets $str to 3 (the length)
echo 'ABC';                    // outputs 'ABC'
echo $str;                     // outputs the value of $str (i.e. '3')
```

hence

```
'5.3', then 'ABC' then '3'
```

giving

```
5.3ABC3
```

Comment: But Why 5`.3` first then `ABC` and then `3`? I know the mechanisim but according to code it should be `ABC5.33`?

Comment: Because `printf()` generates `output` (in your case, the value '5.3') as well as setting a variable value... it effectively does an echo itself... "__Output__ a formatted string".... you're executing the printf() as your first line, so it's the first output sent to php://output

Answer (score 1):

You gave the answer yourself: `printf` outputs a formatted string and returns the length of the string.

So:

```
$str = printf('%.1f', '5.34'); // prints 5.3
echo 'ABC';                    // prints ABC
echo $str;                     // prints 3
```

Which altogether is: 5.3ABC3